# Blocks and passing objects as arguments

Tags: objective-c

I have an `dispatch_async` call in that call I call a block defined in a variable

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            proceedDataBlock(callbackObj, buffer, mbo);
            free(buffer);
        });
```

In the "inner" block I do some stuff with my buffer (const char *) and create an obj-c object and pass it to my callbackobj like

```
Table *dataList = [[Table alloc] init ...];
[callbackObj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(recieveDataModelsFinished:) withObject:[dataList autorelease] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

My callback obj does

```
-(void)recieveDataModelsFinished:(TableDataList *)dataList
{
    self.tableDataList = dataList;
}
```

which is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TableDataList *tableDataList;
```

why gets dealloc get called for my Table object after my callback is done?

Comment: is dealloc also being called on the callbackObj?

Comment: no I have breakpoints there and it get never hit, its a uitableview which should be never dealloced in the app

Comment: is recieveDataModelsFinished: actually executed? Maybe your reference to callbackObj is nil

Comment: it gets called, I try it now without the block and gdc stuff and it happens although

Comment: Maybe your datalist object is first created and put into an autorelease pool. But before your callback method is executed, the run loop is entered, and the autorelease pool is emptied. If so, you would assign nil to your property. Could you check there if datalist is still valid or already nil?

Comment: its not nil at this moment but when I delete the autorelease before returning it works but when I call release the right time, I get "message sent to dealloced instance" in my Table objects dealloc for the properties it have

Comment: What do you mean by "the right time"? If your dataList object is not autoreleased, it is passed with a retain count of 1 to your callback object, and retained there again. So you could call release immediately after assignment to your tableDataList property. It should be released then when your callback object is released itself.

Comment: I mean when it should be released. The callback object should not be released (its the tableview itself). I have now comment mostly everything out and the strange thing is something very similiar works in a concept app without problems.
I dont see what can I comment out anymore to see what happens there

Comment: Again, if dataList is not autoreleased, and assigned to the tableDataList property, it has a retain count of 2. If your callback object is deallocated, the retain count is decremented to 1. So it should be possible to release it "the right time". If you get the error message that it is deallocated already, somebody must have released it before. Maybe you can set a breakpoint in the dealloc method of your dataList object?

Comment: Thats the problem I have breakpoints everywhere but the dealloc method first gets called when I get the error.And its nothing special there its a property of a NSMutableArray. Thanks for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26271/discussion-between-reinhard-manner-and-sebastian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard this in the Apple Forums:
"If you get that message only when stepping through the code in the debugger then this is a know problem with the debugger. The debugger messages objects when you step through the code to get their description. If an object is dealloced but is still in scope the debugger will still message the dealloced object, resulting in the console output about messaging a deallocated instance."
So I hope its a problem with the debugger.